# fprintf() prints 0 instead of full float value (conversion issue?)

Tags: c, double, precision, flags, printf

I'm having problems with some sample code I got from Boulanger and Lazzarini's 'The Audio Programming Book'. It's supposed to generate values for a sine wave, but when I run it I'm just getting values of -0.0000000 and 0.0000000, instead of the expected values between -1.0 and +1.0. I've watched the values as it runs using breakpoints and it all looks good, but when it runs (in either debug or release mode) it gives me bad values.

I'm using Xcode 3.2.6 on MacOSX 10.6.8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI (3.141592654)
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 

  int i, nsamps;
  double samp;
  double twopi = 2.0 * M_PI;
  double angleincr;

  nsamps = 50;
  angleincr = twopi * nsamps;

  for (i=0; i < nsamps; i++) {
    samp = sin(angleincr*i);
    fprintf(stdout, "%lf\n", samp);
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: You're always incrementing by 2 PI, what else do you expect?

Comment: Not your problem, but this is also a very bad way to do the math. As the angle grows, the amount of precision will get less and less, eventually reaching zero. You should instead keep a variable that's not scaled by `M_PI`, subtract the integer portion after each loop iteration, and scale it by `2*M_PI` as the last thing you do before passing it to `sin`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> samp = sin(angleincr*i);
> ```

In your code `angleincr*i` is always a multiple of 2π so the result will indeed be 0.

Comment: Thanks guys. I realised my mistake. `angleincr` is meant to be `= twopi / nsamps`, not multiplied... *Facepalm*...

Answer (score 0):

`"%lf"` is not a valid format specifier for `printf`. Could it be that on your system this tries to interpret the double argument as a `long double`?

Comment: It is explicitly allowed, in the section on `fprintf`, the part about the length modifier `l` ends "or has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier." (May not have been in C89, I don't know that.)

Comment: @DanielFischer, right the standard says. My man page on linux doesn't, so no idea if glibc will just ignore it or try to do something clever. And even less idea what MacOS will do with it.

Comment: My man page says, in the "Conforming to" section, that the functions conform to C89 and C99, so they should duly ignore the `l` in `lf`. Probably it wasn't deemed worthwhile to include it in the description above because it's rather pointless? But yeah, not all implementations are conforming, even if they claim to be.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
angleincr = twopi / nsamps;
```

according to page 159 of the Audio Programming Book.